# No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_() at 0x6fc868a8"

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, libstdc++

I'm using MinGW (originally installed with mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe) in combination with Eclipse for C/C++ (Indigo SR2) under Windows 7 Starter 32bit and I've just upgraded to gcc/g++ 4.7.0 :

```
mingw-get update
mingw-get upgrade
```

I fixed the problem of Eclipse keeping the old version's reference ( https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206372#c2 )

But when I try to run a program as simple as this one, it crashes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "one = " << 1 << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I tried debugging, the problem seems to come from the `cout` line:

```
cout << "one = " << 1 << "\n";
```

If I step over it, Eclipse signals me this error:

```
No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_() at 0x6fc868a8"
```

Here is a screenshot of the IDE just after clicking "Step Over" that line:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QexxQ.png

The same program worked fine before, but now it doesn't.

I've even created a new project (I didn't touch anything in the compiler/linker options), but the same problem remains.

Does anyone have a solution, please ?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Your debugger cannot find the source. Perhaps your object/map files need updating?

Comment: Well it is looking for the source files for the MinGW libs. I'd imagine that perhaps you are hitting "Step Into" rather than "step over".
If you want you could try rebuilding the standard libraries, and ensuring that the project is correctly pointing to the library source files (if you have them... sure you are not just using a DLL?).

Comment: As I said, I create a new project in Eclipse, I wrote the program (exactly the same code that I mentioned before) and clicked on run: it crashed.
I didn't do anything else. It compiles, but crashes when I run it.
And, I actually clicked on "Step Over".

Comment: Hmmmm, strange... Are you linking against a different version of the runtime libraries than you are loading at runtime?

Comment: I don't know. How can I know that ?

Comment: It seems that some other programmers are having the same problem in here http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Program-crashes-when-build-Clang-with-mingw-gcc-4-7-0-td3943583.html but nobody has a solution :(

Comment: After completely removing/reinstalling g++ 4.7 and eclipse, the problem is still the same. Conclusion: it's a g++ bug :'( . So I downgraded to the last gcc/g++ 4.6 (i.e. 4.6.2) and, as expected, everything is just fine... I must admit that it's a little bit frustrating from the 4.7 ... I just wanted to experiment a little bit with C++11 ... I guess that I should wait some months for the bug to be fixed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it ! :D

As mentioned by Dennis it appears that the runtime dll is different than the one using when linking.

Actually, Eclipse linked against **C:\mingw\bin\libstdc++-6.dll** but when executing, another one was used (i.e. **C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll** >_<) because [**gnuplot**](http://www.gnuplot.info/)  (that I installed a long time ago, nice piece of software by the way ;) ) added its installation directory to the **PATH** (even though C:\mingw\bin was in the PATH too) (it added some other environment variables as well)

I was so mad, I removed everything related to gnuplot lol (i.e. its path from PATH, its environment variables and I uninstalled the program). I also removed Cygwin (even though it wasn't in the PATH, but I haven't use it for a long time, so...)

Then, I upgraded to 4.7

```
mingw-get update
mingw-get upgrade
```

I also did the Eclipse thing

And now everything is fine:

```
one = 1
```

:)

```
C:\Windows\System32>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Windows\System32>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If it helps, I used [**Dependency Walker**](http://dependencywalker.com/) to determine what runtime dll was used by the executable (just load the exe in Dependency Walker, then, right-click on LIBSTDC++-6.DLL > Properties )

Comment: Yep Dependency Walker is a valuable tool. :) Glad you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know this question is well answered, but I just want to share my experience since I was confused by it for a long time (yep I haven't coded in C++ for a long time lol)

I realized that it happens because I install MinGW 4.8.1 when install JAVA eclipse and delete the old version (maybe 4.6.2 I don't remember clearly), and the dll was nowhere to find.

I didn't change anything in Path. What I had done is just reinstall the MinGW, click and click, and update all lib files it offers, and then cin & cout work.
Well I really have no idea for why and wth is going on, but thx it works now.